# Cannot find all the addins loaded from XLStart folder in VSTO

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, vsto, excel-addins, xla

I have some xla and xll files in the `XLStart` folder. In C# I would like to find out the addins that are currently loaded.

These addins are not accessible using `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AddIns` but I found this `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.VBE.VBProjects` from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vsto/thread/23e16392-d6de-430d-b282-7897a8fff2e0). The problem with using `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.VBE.VBProjects` is that it doesn't list all my xla and xll files.

Any ideas to list all the addins loaded from `XLStart` folder?

Answer (score 1):

Any Excel file, including add-ins, that are loaded from the XLSTART directory will, by default, NOT be part of the `Addins` collection.

An add-in file loaded from XLSTART will be visible in the VBE, but because it is an add-in, the file is not visible in Excel, and it is not enumerable in the `Workbooks` collection.

Enumerating the VBE projects is one approach, but it requires the VBE to be accessible under the user's Excel security settings, and when inspecting a project, you need to be aware projects that are saved/unsaved, protected/unprotected, and those that are projects referenced by other projects.

However, just because the Workbooks collection won't *enumerate* the non-visible add-ins doesn't mean that they aren't *in* the `Workbooks` collection.

If you know the name of the add-in that you're looking for, you can use:

```
ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.get_Item("MyAddin.xlam")
```

So, if you enumerate the file names in the XLSTART directory, and then check that:

```
ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.get_Item(addinName).FullName == addinFullName
```

For *each file*, then you'll know which XLSTART files are loaded.